# Add intro or full image to a component/module Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, images

I'm not good in php, more a css/sass html specialist. I had an module (latest articles) and I needed to add the intro image. With Joomla 3 I did it like this:

```
<div class="nieuwsfotos" style="background-image: url(<?php $images = json_decode($item->images); ?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>)" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>" /> </div>
```

This made it possible to add the image in front of the headline. But this does not work for Joomla 4.

Anybody knows how to code this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the equivalent of what you had in Joomla 3 by going into System / Templates then clicking on Cassiopeia (or whatever site template you're using) Details and Files, and then creating a template override of the module `mod_articles_latest`.

Once you've created the override, in the Editor tab edit the module file `default.php` which is found under /templates/cassiopeia / html / mod_articles_latest / default.php.

Place your `<div>` code around the `<a>` element in that file, ie replace:

```
<a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="name">
        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
    </span>
</a>
```

with

```
<div class="nieuwsfotos" style="background-image: url(<?php $images = json_decode($item->images); ?><?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>)" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>" />
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="name">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you need help with template overrides then there are plenty of tutorials online, eg https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/july-2022/joomla-override-management,
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla
https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides
(although some of these are a bit outdated).

Comment: I needed to do a bit more to make ik work, but it does work now:

`<div class="nieuwsblokitems">
<?php
 $article_images  = json_decode($item->images);
 $article_image   = '';
 $article_image_alt   = '';
 if(isset($article_images->image_intro) && !empty($article_images->image_intro)) {
 $article_image  = $article_images->image_intro;
 $article_image_alt  = $article_images->image_intro_alt;
 }?> 
    <div class="nieuwsfoto">
 <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><span  class="nieuwsfotos" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $article_image;?>" /></span></a>  </div> `

Comment: Looks good. Glad you got it sorted.